# Maintain visibility of a form-textinput when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, session-storage

In my HTML I have a form, where a user can select the checkbox "other" and a textbox appears. Otherwise the textbox is hidden. Below you can find my code. *But* if the user selects "other", types in his text und submits the form, the textbox is hidden again-although the checkbox maintain checked (saved in localStorage). I cannot find my mistake here.

**Form:**

```
<label class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" name="filetype" type="checkbox" id="other" value="" onclick="save()">
       <span class="form-check-label"
             <input placeholder="e.g. 'msg'" name="other" onsubmit="save();" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="otherValue" value="{{extension}}">
       </span>
</label> <!-- form-check -->
```

**Visible/Hidden**

```
 <!--"Other"-filter-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var otherCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[id="other"]');
        var otherText = document.querySelector('input[id="otherValue"]');
        otherText.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        otherCheckbox.onchange = function(){
            if(otherCheckbox.checked) {
                otherText.style.visibility = 'visible';
                otherCheckbox.value = otherText.value;
                save();
            } else {
                otherText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        };
      </script>
```

Tried to solve this Problem by saving the info in the **sessionStorage** but it still does not work.

```
 <!--Save Checkbox-State-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        const checkboxen = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]")].map(inp => inp.id); //list of all checkbox-IDs

        function save(){
            for (var i = 0 ; i< checkboxen.length; i++){
                var id = checkboxen[i];
                var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
                sessionStorage.setItem(id,checkbox.checked);
            }
            var other = document.getElementById('otherValue');
            sessionStorage.setItem('otherValue',other.style.visibility);
        }
        function load(){
            for (var i = 0 ; i< checkboxen.length; i++){
                var id = checkboxen[i];
                var checked =JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(id));
                document.getElementById(id).checked = checked;
            }
            var other = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('otherValue'));
            document.getElementById('otherValue').style.visibility = other;
        }
        function deleteCheckbox(){         
            sessionStorage.clear();
        }
       </script>
```

Thanks for any help <3

Comment: And that function `load` gets called when and where …?

Comment: If the checkbox remain properly checked after the submit, you can just check its state when the page reloads and set the textbox visibility accordingly.

Comment: @04FS in the body-element `onload = "load()"`

Comment: @David how do I write "when the page reloads" in JS? With `var other = document.getElementById('other');
        var otherText = document.getElementById('otherValue');

        if (other.checked){
            otherText.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
                otherText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }' nothing happens...

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @David Thank u David, this solved my Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var other = document.getElementById('other');
        var otherText =document.querySelector('input[id="otherValue"]');
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if (other.checked){
                otherText.style.visibility = 'visible';
                otherText.value = "{{extension}}";
                other.value  = "{{extension}}";
            } else {
                otherText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                 otherText.value = "";
            }
         });
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain what you solved and how, so future people reading these questions might get something out of it.

Comment: If the checkbox remain checked after submitting it, you can check its state when the page reloads and set the textbox visibility accordingly, therefore use  `$(document).ready(function()` thx to @David

Comment: I meant more that you should amend your answer with extra info. You don't have to explain it to me :)

Answer (score 0):

with [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       var other = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
       $('input').prop('checked', other);
    });

    $('input').on('change', function() {
       localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
       console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this does unfortunatley not work for me. When clicking one checkbox now, all checkboxes are checked, but the textfield remains hidden...

Comment: you can select special selector with `$('selector') -> $('input[name=other]')` and try again.

Comment: I am not really familiar with jQuery. Could you please tell me where to make those changes?